# How can I solve this?

Tags: improper-integrals

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}}{x^2+b^2} dx $$

Comment: contour integration?

Comment: Please spare us you quick drafts.

Comment: We can transform the problem into solving an ODE $$f'(a) - b^2 f(a)  + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^{3/2}} = 0$$ by defining the integral as $f(a)$ and using $f(a) = -\frac{d}{da}\int \frac{e^{-ax^2}}{x^2+b^2} = -\frac{1}{b^2}\frac{d}{da}\left[\int e^{-ax^2} - f(a)\right]$ together with $\int e^{-ax^2} = \sqrt{\pi/a}$.

Comment: this integral containes the error function

Comment: @YvesDaoust He is required to show his work, and he is doing so.

Comment: @GFauxPas: we spend lots of time laying out our solutions properly.

Comment: Thank you @Winther, I would never think to transform this into an ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'sort-of' elementary way to proceed [without complex analysis] is as follows. Write 
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+b^2}=\int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s(x^2+b^2)}
$$
and exchange the order of integrals to get
$$
I= \int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s b^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ x^2 e^{-(\alpha+s)x^2}
$$
$$
=\partial_\alpha\int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s b^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ e^{-(\alpha+s)x^2}
$$
$$
=\partial_\alpha\int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s b^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha+s}}
$$
and changing variables $\alpha+s=u$
$$
=\sqrt{\pi}\partial_\alpha \left[e^{\alpha b^2}\int_\alpha^\infty du\frac{e^{-b^2 u}}{\sqrt{u}}\right]\ .
$$
The integrand admits a quite simple antiderivative
$$
\int du \frac{e^{-b^2 u}}{\sqrt{u}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\ \text{erf}\left(b \sqrt{u}\right)}{b}+C\ ,
$$
in terms of the error function. The finishing touch should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the given integral is simply
$$\begin{eqnarray*} 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+b^2}e^{-a x^2}\,dx &\stackrel{x\mapsto bz}{=}&2b\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^2}{z^2+1}e^{-a b^2 z^2}\,dz\\&=&\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}-b\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-a b^2 z^2\right)}{z^2+1}\,dz\end{eqnarray*}$$
and we may tackle the last integral through the Fourier transform:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-a b^2 z^2\right)}{z^2+1}\,dz =\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{ab^2}} \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-s}\exp\left(-\frac{s^2}{4ab^2}\right)\,ds$$ 
getting a value of the (complementary) [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function) by completing the square:
$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+b^2}e^{-a x^2}\,dx = \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}-\pi b e^{ab^2}\text{Erfc}\left(b\sqrt{a}\right)}.}$$